# Load variables into async JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I am trying to get some variables into a script I am loading. Currently, I have like

```
window.myApp = {
    id: ''
};
```

And I am loading the javascript like

```
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://blah.com/widget.js';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
  })();
```

`widget.js` has the namespace `window.myApp` and I am trying to get the `.id` into it ? How can I do that?

Comment: if widget.js is in page before you call the script insert use it any way you need to as  `myApp.id` .......if not before you have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within widget.js you could do this:

```
var alreadyDefinedProps = window.myApp;

window.myApp = {
   // whatever properties widget.js has currently
}

if (alreadyDefinedProps) {
   for (var prop in alreadyDefinedProps)
       window.myApp[prop] = alreadyDefinedProps[prop];
}
```

That is, store a reference to the existing `window.myApp` object, then set `window.myApp` to another object, then copy the properties across. You could add an `if` test to handle the case where the same property is defined in both JS files.

Comment: If you give it another name you don't really need the `alreadyDefinedProps` variable: that was a way to let you use the same namespace name but add properties to it, and I used the `for` loop to allow for future expansion beyond just a single id property. You may like to adapt some of the techniques from this article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: thanks for the link. still a little confused however how to get the window.myApp into widget.js as at the moment - using your above technique - it's still not loading ?

Comment: Is the initial code you showed in your question that defined `windowmyApp = { id:'' }` in the same page as the one where you create the script element?

Comment: dohh!! oh just figured it out ... :) coffee time one thinks. awesome and thanks for the help and hanging round! you rock!

Answer (score 0):

You need an event handler for the `load` event of the script tag you're inserting, like so:

```
if (s.attachEvent) {
    s.attachEvent("onload", function () {
        window.myApp.id = '';
    });
} else {
    s.addEventListener("load", function () {
        window.myApp.id = '';
    });
}
```

This adds the callback, even for IE, for the script's `load` event. Insert this code after the line that reads `s.async = true;`

Comment: thanks :) is there any way to do this in the widget.js instead ?

Answer (score 0):

After you script is loaded, you can either read or write properties from the myApp object.  To detect when an async script is loaded, you can capture an event when it's loaded.  See [this reference](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) for details on how to do that.